# Creat JAR from .jardesc in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, jar

I have a question with respect to compiling java codes and building a jar file on Eclipse platform. I would like to know if the `Create JAR` option on eclipse from a `.jardesc` file will still create a JAR file inspite of errors in the compiled Java codes? If yes, how can i enable this option in my Ant build xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit your `.jardesc` in Eclipse (*Open With* – *JAR Export Wizard*), you can modify the behavior regarding errors/warnings on page two of the wizard:
[image: Eclipse JAR Export Wizard (Page 2) "Export class files with compile errors"].

This apparently toggles the attributes `exportErrors` and `exportWarnings`, respectively, at XPath `/jardesc/options` in the `.jardesc` file.

As far as the behavior of a corresponding Ant build file is concerned, you should probably take a look at the `failonerror` parameter of the [Javac Task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).